# Printing to Google Cloud Print using iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, printing

I have been trying to print a PDF file to Google cloud print using the following code. Instead of actually printing the document, it is only printing a string that shows the location of the file as well as the file name. I would like to have it print the actual document.

We can assume that the data being passed into this method is valid as it seems to be finding the correct printer from calls to cloud prints /search

**Update: The code is updated from its original format to include some multi-part form data**

```
              NSString *currentPDFFileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestPDF" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:currentPDFFileName];
    NSData *validPDF = [[NSString stringWithString:@"%PDF"] dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if (!(pdfData && [[pdfData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)] isEqualToData:validPDF])) 
    {
        NSLog (@"Not valid");
    }

    NSLog (@"%@", currentPDFFileName);
    NSLog (@"%@", [currentPDFFileName lastPathComponent]);

    //create the body
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    //create the POST vars
    NSString *thePrinter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"printerid\"\r\n\r\n%@", printerID];
    NSString *pdf = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"content\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", [currentPDFFileName lastPathComponent]];
    NSString *theContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"contentType\"\r\n\r\n%@", contentType];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", @"----foo"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[thePrinter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", @"----foo"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[pdf dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", @"----foo"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[theContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", @"----foo"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:pdfData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", @"----foo"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *pdfRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit"]];
    [pdfRequest setValue:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=----foo" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [pdfRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [pdfRequest setHTTPBody:body];


    [self.authenticate authorizeRequest:pdfRequest completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        NSString *output = nil;
        if(error) {
            output = [error description];
        } else {
            NSURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:pdfRequest
                                                 returningResponse:&response
                                                             error:&error];
            if(data) {
                output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            } else {
                output = [error description];
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"%@", output);
    }];
```

Comment: Are you able to implement in your code ? i am also trying to do the same but no success..